# What is "God's Number" for Specific CFOP Algorithms on the 3X3 Rubik's Cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube, computer-science, speedsolving

## CFOP: What is God's Number for PLL and OLL Algorithms?

[image: god]

I have been "speedcubing" on and off for 5-6 years now using CFOP and throughout my experience have come across many different algorithms for the same PLL or OLL cases. Obviously, the number of turns in an algorithm does not imply a faster solution due to possible awkward positioning - much like how it would not be probable that a human would solve a Rubik's cube with its optimal at most 20 turn solution (God's Number). However, just looking at the number of turns, what would be the optimal number of turns for each PLL or OLL case? Have there been tests using God's Algorithm, and if so is there a list of them somewhere?

Comment: What is "God's Number"? (The image isn't very explanatory.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor the lowest number of turns needed to solve a 3X3 Rubik's Cube for all cases - which is 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such list is on the following site by Bernard Helmstetter:
http://www.ai.univ-paris8.fr/~bh/cube/

The last link on that page is a list of all 1212 configurations (rotations and reflections removed), and their average solution length is 12.58 moves.